# How to fix "where" clause in this situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the code:

```
select
  S.Employee_ID,
  ((S.Salary / 30) * (count(A.Att_check)) + S.Bonus - S.Loan) as [TotalSalary] 
from Salary as S, Attendance as A
where count(A.Att_check) in (
    select count(A.Att_check)
    from Attendance as A
    where A.Att_check = 'attend'
    group by A.Employee_ID
)
  and A.Employee_ID = S.Employee_ID
```

And here is the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the `WHERE` clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a `HAVING` clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

It places on the 4th line from the top

Comment: The error message is very clear. you need to [use *having*](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-having/)

Comment: Nothing do do with your question, but you should also consider to stop using this ancient join style

Comment: Don't use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Stop cramming your code together. Make an effort to develop good habits and use best practices.

Comment: Seems like you need to add `GROUP BY S.Employee_ID` plus aggregation on the `SELECT` columns as well as move the condition to `HAVING`. also the subquery is unnecessary and you could just use `HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN A.Att_check = 'attend' THEN 1 END)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't try your query but, but from the error you are getting, you might want to try this:

change:

```
where count(A.Att_check) in ..
```

to:

```
having count(A.Att_check) in ..
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following `GROUP BY`:

```sql
GROUP BY S.Employee_ID , S.Salary , S.BONUS , s.LOAN
```

```sql
SELECT      S.Employee_ID,
            ((S.Salary/30) * (COUNT(A.Att_check)) + S.Bonus-S.Loan) as [TotalSalary] 
FROM        Salary as S, 
            Attendance as A
WHERE       1=1
--AND       COUNT(A.Att_check) 
IN (
  SELECT    COUNT(A.Att_check) 
  FROM      Attendance as A 
  WHERE     A.Att_check = 'attend' 
  GROUP BY  A.Employee_ID
)
AND         A.Employee_ID = S.Employee_ID
GROUP BY    S.Employee_ID, 
            S.Salary, 
            S.BONUS, 
            S.LOAN
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: A good "answer" will explain how this code addresses the issue.